# Android - My app replaces the app which shared its content

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

I'm developing an app that receives data using intents(ACTION_SEND). I've discovered a weird issue when I'm sharing content from Chrome(only happens in Chrome 83 or above, older versions can't reproduce the issue) for instance, if the content is only selected text, for example, the data reaches my app correctly, but if the content shared is a URL, it reaches my app, but suddenly my app replaces Chrome in the app switcher. So, if I have my app and Chrome opened, after the data sharing I have two instances of my app(even if the Chrome icon appears in top of that window, if I tap it, opens my app).

Any ideas about what is going on here? It's worth to notice that I can't reproduce this using Firefox.

My activity code:

```
class MainActivity : HybridActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        Log.d("MyApp", "onCreate")
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val testButton = Button(this)
        setContentView(testButton)
    }

    override fun onStart(){
        super.onStart()
        var bundle = intent.getExtras();
        Log.d("MyApp", "onStart intent tostr: " + intent.toString())

        if (bundle != null) {
            bundle.keySet().forEach {
                Log.d("MyApp", "EXTRA:" + it + "=" + bundle.get(it));
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        Log.d("MyApp", "onResume")
    }
}
```

Intent filter is defined in the manifests like this:

```
<intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
          <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
          <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
        </intent-filter>
```

PS: Don't know if this is related but I've changed the launch mode in the manifest to `singleInstance` and the issue still is reproducible...

PS2: I have added this activity dump, produced just as the issue appeared:
https://gist.github.com/Leprosy/f63bf02bb1c2887f0e419799d98635ab

Comment: You can get more information about what is going on by using `adb shell dumpsys activity activities`. This will show you all running tasks and all activities in those tasks. If you have a `singleInstance` `Activity` and Chrome is launching that `Activity` into its own task, then thats very wrong. Can you repro the problem and copy the output of the `adb` command into the question (or put it in the cloud somewhere and post a link to it)?

Comment: I have edited the question and added the link to the gist that contains the log. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app is actually not replacing chrome, but instead the share link intent receiver activity from your app arrives at the top of the chrome [task](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack). It's still the chrome task, it's just that the top activty is from your app. This ensures that pressing back results in going back to chrome, even if you would switch apps a few times first.

As a workaround, you could detect this, and in that case, create a new intent to launch a new activity and close the one that directly received it.

Edit: I tested this and it can be done in the following way:

```
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
import android.os.Bundle

class ExternalTextReceiverActivity : Activity() {
    val CUSTOM_EXTRA_NAME = "RELAUNCHED"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        if (!intent.getBooleanExtra(CUSTOM_EXTRA_NAME, false)) {
            this.finish()
            intent.addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.putExtra(CUSTOM_EXTRA_NAME, true);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // The rest of your onCreate code here

    }
}
```

If you only want this for chrome specifically, then you can use this code:

```
import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
import android.os.Bundle

class ExternalTextReceiverActivity : Activity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        if (intent.getIntExtra("org.chromium.chrome.extra.TASK_ID", -1) == this.taskId) {
            this.finish()
            intent.addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // The rest of your onCreate code here
    }
}
```

Combine in both cases with `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` or `android:launchMode="singleTask"` for your Activity in the Android Manifest to make sure it does not open multiple tasks for this same activity.

Comment: I thought of doing something like that but my code always start already in the context of my app replacing Chrome, so I can't detect this happening at all.

Comment: I edited my answer to add sample code on how to do the workaround.

Answer (score 2):

### Update 2

So I have done some more research and it seems that this only happens when using the android sharesheet. When the app that shares the data uses the intent resolver the activity is opened in a new task/instance. For example the sharing function in firefox does handle it correctly. Unfortunately I could not find anything related to this and how you could fix it.

#### Original Answer

I think that this a wanted behavior as your app is handling the url and it is not opened in your app.

#### Update

This is what the offical docs say about implicit deep links you are using:

An implicit deep link is a URI that refers to a specific destination in an app. When a URI is invoked—for example, when a user clicks a link—Android can then open your app to the corresponding destination.

When triggering an implicit deep link, the state of the back stack depends on whether the implicit Intent was launched with the `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag:

- If the flag is set, the task back stack is cleared and replaced with the deep link destination. As with explicit deep linking, when nesting graphs, the start destination from each level of nesting—that is, the start destination from each  element in the hierarchy—is also added to the stack. This means that when a user presses the Back button from a deep link destination, they navigate back up the navigation stack just as though they entered your app from its entry point.
- If the flag is not set, you remain on the task stack of the previous app where the implicit deep link was triggered. In this case, the Back button takes you back to the previous app, while the Up button starts your app's task on the hierarchical parent destination within your navigation graph.

From my understanding that means, that only the app that launches your app can change this behavior.

Source: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link#implicit

Comment: Interesting...I haven't found any documentation about this, and as I said before, this is not happening with any version of Chrome before 83.

Comment: likely it was handlet diffrent by chrome before 83

Comment: And it does not only happen with your app

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to disable this "feature"...it's weird

Comment: Thanks for the update! I'll check this documentation.

Comment: If I understand correctly, a deep link is something I put on a website that allows Chrome to fire up my app, right? What I'm using here is the "Share link" feature of the browser. Why is deep linking taking place in that case?

Comment: When you open a link from anywhere on your phone and on your phone is an app installed that can handle this link the system will prompt you to choose if you want to open it in that app. simplified this is called deep linking